# NavigationLink disappear in iOS 14.5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14

navigationlink disapear in ios 14.5? and the textfield can't input number,also.
but it's work correctly find in ios 15.0

```
NavigationLink(destination: chart(), label: {
                Image(systemName: "chart.line.uptrend.xyaxis.circle.fill")
                  .resizable()
                  .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                  .foregroundColor(.gray)
                 
              })
NavigationLink(destination: setting(), label: {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                  .resizable()
                  .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                  .foregroundColor(.gray)
                 
              })
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SF Symbol `chart.line.uptrend.xyaxis.circle.fill` is available in iOS 15+. That's the reason why your symbol is not visible (but link should be still tappable though).

I guess you took that icon from SF Symbol app, if so, then check the particular icon's deeper info or toggle the icons from grid view into list and it will show availability right away.

- You can either pick your deployment target friendly icon. Or export it and make a fallback in png format (where you put your png version of SF Symbol in to `Assets.xcassets` )

Check the screenshot here:
[SF Symbols app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezEaX.png)